# How to get values in Xattributes

Tags: c#, linq

First my code

```
XDocument USshardStatus = XDocument.Load("http://status.riftgame.com/na-status.xml");
XDocument EuropeShardStatus = XDocument.Load("http://status.riftgame.com/eu-status.xml");

List<IEnumerable<XAttribute>> USRiftShard = new List<IEnumerable<XAttribute>>();
//Attributes contains values from "online" node, there is 7 elements
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("online")); 
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("name"));
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("locked"));
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("population"));
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("queued"));
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("language"));
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("pvp"));
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("rp"));
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("recommend"));
USRiftShard.Add(USshardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("initialCreationRestriction"));

List<IEnumerable<XAttribute>> EuropeRiftShard = new List<IEnumerable<XAttribute>();
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("online"));
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("name"));
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("locked"));
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("population"));
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("queued"));
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("language"));
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("pvp"));
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("rp"));
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("recommend"));
EuropeRiftShard.Add(EuropeShardStatus.Descendants("shard").Attributes("initialCreationRestriction"));

foreach (IEnumerable<XAttribute> statusUS in USRiftShard)
{

    foreach (XAttribute xatrib in statusUS)
    {
        lvNorthAmericaShard.Items.Add(xatrib.Value);
    }
}
foreach (IEnumerable<XAttribute> statusEU in EuropeRiftShard)
{
    foreach (XAttribute xAttribute in statusEU)
    {
        lvEuropeShard.Items.Add(xAttribute.Value);
    }
}
```

Now the question, how do i construct LINQ query so i can display values from XAttribute elements in listview, the way i have it right now works, but it is displaying only in first column. It should display "online" node in status column, "name" in Shard name column, "type" in Server type column etc.

Can anybody give me advice?

[image: Screen]

Comment: I made them in the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
XDocument USshardStatus = XDocument.Load("http://status.riftgame.com/na-status.xml");
var items = from node in USshardStatus.Descendants("shard")
            select new ListViewItem(new string[] { 
                    //select attributes what you need
                    node.Attribute("online").Value,  
                    node.Attribute("name").Value,
                    node.Attribute("locked").Value,
                    node.Attribute("population").Value,
                    node.Attribute("queued").Value,
                })).ToArray();
lvNorthAmericaShard.Items.AddRange(items);
```

**UPDATE**
or move this to function like this

```
private ListViewItem[] GetItems(string url, params string[] attrNames)
{
    return (from node in XDocument.Load(url).Descendants("shard")
            select new ListViewItem(
               attrNames.Select(attr=>node.Attribute(attr).Value).ToArray()
            )).ToArray();
}
```

and use it like

```
lvNorthAmericaShard.Items.AddRange(GetItems("http://status.riftgame.com/na-status.xml", 
    "online", 
    "name", 
    "locked", 
    "population", 
    "queued", 
    "language"));
```

Comment: I like both solutions, both work for me, but Grundy's is easy to read and understand. I prefer readability, especially if it is in method form. 
Cheers and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to loop through all elements and all them to your listView

```
foreach (XElement element in USshardStatus.Descendants().
    Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "status").
    Descendants().
    Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "shart"))
        {
            //Add items to your listviews.
            string onlineValue = element.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "online").SingleOrDefault().Value;
            string name = element.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "name").SingleOrDefault().Value;
            //So on...
            string[] row = {onlineValue, name};
            listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(row));
        }
```

This works for me. Make sure the `View` property of your ListView is set to "Details".